# Find a table in excel and understand formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have inherited a spreadsheet with an IRR calculation that has the following formula:

```
{=TABLE(E47,C41)}
```

I would guess it is a structured reference referring to a table, but I can't find the table.

Q1: What is the formula doing? It pulls in an NPV amount, which is then used for IRR, so it seems to be some sort of look up.

Q2: If a formula is referring to a table, how do I find the table?  I can see many tables being recalculated, but can't find them.

Comment: Is `TABLE()` a custom macro?

Comment: Is there another cell somewhere that has a formula operating on this particular table?  It seems as if TABLE just groups the cells together for another operation like a "what-if" analysis.

Comment: good thought, but i don't see any macros. thx

Comment: [Reference](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-onevariable-data-table-in-excel-20.html) for my other comment

Answer (score 3):

This is a **data table**, normally produced from (in Excel 2007) Data > Data Tools> What-if Analysis > Data Table...

It seems to be a 2-way table so the reference formula should be in the top-left cell of the table. `E47` and `C41` will be referred to in this formula, and the data table substitutes these values with the values in the leading row and column of the data table. You can use this feature to produce, for instance, a multiplication table.

See the following for more information:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282856

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/teach-two-variable-excel-data-tables-with-real-life-examples/1042399

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest to way to go to the Table referred in a formula (See Example 1 below), is to use the Pull down menu, called the Name Box, just above Column A, to the left of the Formula bar (See Picture 1 below).

This is the same Pull down we use when we 'name' our own group of cells. Tags: Excel Table Identification. Where is my Excel Table?

Example 1:

```
=Table22[@[Circuit Type]] or =YourExcelFile.xlsx!Table224[@[Table Column Title]])
```

[image: Image of Top left Corner of Excel Sheet]